# Making materialize card selectable

Tags: html, angularjs, materialize

Is there a way to make each entire card selectable? I am only using html, materialize at the moment but the app is in angular too.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="./assets/SVSunset.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">Agenda</span>
          <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>Whats happening when and where</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="./assets/SVSunset.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">Map</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>Map with markers for church, reception etc</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="./assets/SVSunset.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">Confetti</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>DIY some eco friendly confetti :)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by selectable? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was easier than i thought by wrapping an `<a href="">` around the cards `div` like below:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="./assets/SVSunset.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">Agenda</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>Whats happening when and where</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="./assets/SVSunset.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">Map</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>Map with markers for church, reception etc</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="./assets/SVSunset.jpg">
          <span class="card-title">Confetti</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>DIY some eco friendly confetti :)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
```